# Get the number of times the number "1" appears in my list, without using if statements or empty lists in for loop?

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

How do you get the number of times the number `1` appears in the following list:

```py
list = [1,2,3,4,5,1,1]
```

I have tried the following and it works, but I want to do it without creating an empty list and the if statement, but what I really want is a count of the number of times `1` appears instead of a list with only 1s and then count them.

```py
list = [1,2,3,4,5,1,1]

list_1s = []

for i in list:

    if i == 1:
       list_1s.append(i)

    else:
       pass


n_1s = len(list_1s)

print(n_1s)
```

Answer (score 1):

lst = [1,2,3,4,5,1,1]

Using list comprehensions to solve it -

```
count_1s = len([i for i in lst if i==1])
print(count_1s)
    3
```

Comment: Hahaha thanks! it looks ridiculous what I did compared to your answer